# How can i get keys from each object in array (postgresql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I done

```
let statuses = await t.any(`SELECT DISTINCT status FROM mails`)
```

and got

```
        "statuses": [
        {
            "status": "error"
        },
        {
            "status": "success"
        }
    ]
```

How can I get array with keys of objects ? ['error', 'success'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `status` is a `jsonb` column (which it should be), you can do:

```
select distinct st.status
from mails m
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(m.status -> 'statuses') as st(status)
```

If `status` is a `json` column you will need to use `json_array_elements()` instead

Comment: I get error in postman : "operator does not exist: text -> unknown". Why?

Comment: Then your `status` column is neither `jsonb` (which it really should be) nor `json`. You need to cast it before you can treat it as a proper JSON value: `m.status::jsonb`. But you should fix our table design and ALTER the column to be a `jsonb` type